# How to strip the details required to add into "adding trusted sites?"

Tags: powershell

Our application uses url file which contains the following details

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://MachineName:1800/App/LandingPage.aspx
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://MachineName:1800/App/LandingPage.aspx
```

I need to add this URL to trusted site .

So first i need to get the `http://MachineName` alone

If i run the followind command ,it has the complete line where BASEURL present.

```
$URL = Get-content FileName.url | Select-string -pattern "BASEURL"
```

How to get the content only from `http://MachineName` using powershell?

Answer (score 4):

The [`Select-String`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) cmdlet returns either a boolean or `MatchInfo`. As per [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx):

> Outputs Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo or System.Boolean  By
>   default, the output is a set of MatchInfo objects, one for each match
>   found. If you use the Quiet parameter, the output is a Boolean value
>   indicating whether the pattern was found.

When you got multiple matches without using `-quiet`, you'll get an array of `MatchInfo` objects. The results can be accessed via `Matches[]` array's `Value` property like so,

```
PS C:\> $URL = Get-content \temp\FileName.url | Select-string -pattern "(http://[^:]+)"
PS C:\> $URL

BASEURL=http://MachineName:1800/App/LandingPage.aspx
URL=http://MachineName:1800/App/LandingPage.aspx

PS C:\> $URL[0].Matches[0].value
http://MachineName
PS C:\> $URL[1].Matches[0].value
http://MachineName
```

In order to capture only the BASEURL string without the prefix, use non-capturing group like so,

```
PS C:\> $URL = Get-content \temp\FileName.url | Select-string -pattern "(?:BASEURL=)(http://[^:]+)"
PS C:\> $url

BASEURL=http://MachineName:1800/App/LandingPage.aspx

PS C:\> $url.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
http://MachineName
```